# BASH - How can i have a track of execution? Such as first time and second time run ignore something?

Tags: bash, centos, fedora, archlinux

I have a script which runs when the system boot first time. But that same script second time also used by skiping one command only.

So i was trying with variable but it seems there is no way to track it.

E.g: `/var/tmp/runme.sh` << this same script is to use

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo pipe;
mkfifo pipe1;
ps aux | grep Java.jar | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
sleep 1;

#
# Question on this:
# only one time it execute / its my application boot process
# - this is only one time on system startup
#
##############################################################
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && java -cp Java.jar main.Boot &

#
# second time this following should always execute
# This is my software kernel, which crash often 
# on the fly i restart it
#
while true; do cat /var/jpeg1.jpeg >> pipe; done
while true; do cat /var/jpeg2.jpeg >> pipe1; done
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && java -cp Java.jar main.Desktop &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a lockfile :) Eg: at the begining of the script add:

```
lockfile= /var/lock/MyLockFile
if [! -f $lockfile ] then
  touch $lockfile
  ....place your run-once commands here...
fi
```

Please remember to delete $tmpfile in script at system shutdown OR in script at early stage of boot!

Comment: How do i know when system is shutdown or reboot or manually applied `$ sudo init 6 or sudo init 0` and patch my own script to do the necessary management?

Comment: Well, you probably call your script from something like rc.local, aren't you? So just place in it the following squence: rm $lockfile;/path/to/your/script/ScriptName

Answer (score 0):

Create a lock file in `/var/run` (assuming that your system automatically clears `/var/run` on boot - or use `/tmp` if that works better). Check to see if the lock file is present and take different actions based on whether it is.